# How make libswscale FFMpeg library works in android 23+

Tags: android, ffmpeg

**Lib: https://github.com/ser-gik/smoothrescale**

Hello! I have a question about how update this lib and make it works in latest android sdk.

I was working with this lib running in several android sdk and noticed the following:

In Android 30 , with proyect targeting

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1
targetSdkVersion 22

**works without problems.**

In Android 30 , with proyect targeting

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3
targetSdkVersion 23

**Throws the error libswscale.so" has text relocations (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23)**

In Android 31 , with proyect targeting

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1
targetSdkVersion 22

**App show a dialog "This app was built for an older version" and close.**

In Android 31 , with proyect targeting

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3
targetSdkVersion 23

**dlopen failed: library "libsmoothrescale.so" not found.**

The goal is make this lib works in Android 23 until 31 , but with several scenarios I really don´t know where I should begin my investigation and learning.

Should I learn how the lib works in a native level? Is possible make this work only with Android Studio funtionality? Any guide or comment are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: 1) The library is using 32-bit ffmpeg libraries: https://github.com/ser-gik/smoothrescale/tree/master/smoothrescale/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/lib 2) You won't be able to put it in the Google Play store unless 64-bit: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/64-bit 3) I would try to figure out what ffmpeg options create the effect and use a modern ffmpeg library. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Last week i've compiled ffmpeg-4.3.1 with NDK-r23b for Android 12 (target 31) with [ffmpeg-android-maker](https://github.com/Javernaut/ffmpeg-android-maker) without a problem. The output will give you 4 archs including armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64 each have *.so like libswscale.so

Note **ffmpeg-4.4.1 or 5.0** will output vstencxxxx errors in my test when encoding frames (not solved yet) so **DON'T use them yet.**

```
ffmpeg-android-maker.sh --target-abis=arm64-v8a --source-tar=4.3.1 --android-api-level=31

ffmpeg-android-maker.sh --target-abis=armeabi-v7a --source-tar=4.3.1 --android-api-level=21 # Here use lowest support
```

You also need headers from ffmpeg-android-maker/output/include replace

```
smoothrescale/smoothrescale/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/include/*
```

Because *.so needs to work with corresonding header files.
This is why you get error like **libswscale.so" has text relocations**
. Simply replace *.so sometimes not backward compatible.